# Stop TextBlock from resizing container WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a listbox that changes size based on the size of the window. For each item in the listbox, it contains (via DataTemplate):

```
<Grid Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Value="{Binding Path=Progress, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="7,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=OperationTitle}" />

        </Grid>
```

The progress bars are supposed to expand to the size of the listbox, which they do unless the text in the textblock is longer than the listbox. In that case, the textblock and the progressbar become wider than the listbox and a horizontal scroll bar appears at the bottom of the list box.

I want the progressbar and textblock to be as wide as the listbox allows and the text in the textblock to be cut off if it's longer than the listbox.

At the moment, the progress bar width is controlled by its container in one case, and its contents in another. I want it to always be controller by its container.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try binding the width of the progressbar and textblock to the width of the listbox?

Answer (score 0):

Hi if i didnt misinterpreted your question try this

```
 <Grid Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MaxWidth="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Value="{Binding Path=Progress, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Margin="7,0,0,0" Text="OperationTitle" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

I hope this will help and dont forget to set maxWidth of second column of the Grid accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try to add next property to listbox

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
```